# mechanize.Browser() downloads corrupt JPG under Windows, works fine in Linux?

Tags: python, pyqt, mechanize

I have the following code:

```
self.bg_br = mechanize.Browser()   

self.bg_br.retrieve(self.bg_imageurl, "image2.jpg")

self.bg_file2 = open("image.jpg", mode="w")
self.bg_image = self.bg_br.open(self.bg_imageurl).read()
self.bg_file2.write(self.bg_image)
self.bg_file2.close()
```

The problem is that the image.jpg (the one that is downloaded via `.read()` method is corrupted. This is displayed later by Qt (which reports "JPG corrupted" error), and when I try to open the file with a windows application, the image is garbled. It opens fine, but it's garbled.

Via the `.retrieve` method, everything works fine, HOWEVER, the image I am downloading is generated anew every time you visit the link - so that's no good.

What's even more puzzling is that both methods work just fine under linux, however under windows, like I said, the first method gives a corrupt image.

Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to open the file using the `'wb'` mode for your `bg_file2` operation. Under Unix, Python doesn't differentiate between text and binary files, but on Windows it does. To support platform independence, just use the `'wb'` mode to write your image in a binary format. I don't know the internals of mechanize, but my guess is that the `retrieve` method does this as well: you just don't see it as it is abstracted by the library.

For more details, see [this section of the Python docs](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

Comment: Thanks a lot - this worked. I'm not really experienced with Windows.